# How to uninstall specific lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu

Hello I downloaded [Vanilla LXDE](http://www.howtogeek.com/107368/how-to-install-the-lightweight-lxde-desktop-on-ubuntu/) with `sudo apt-get install lxde`, but along with it came all these unwanted windows managers like Lubuntu’s customized LXDE among other things.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean by "all these unwanted windows managers"? AFAIK, there's just the default one window manager for LXDE and that is Openbox.

Answer (score 0):

> The following NEW packages will be installed:   consolekit galculator
>   gpicview gtk2-engines leafpad libck-connector0   libfm-data
>   libfm-extra4 libfm-gtk-data libfm-gtk4 libfm-modules libfm4
>   libmenu-cache-bin libmenu-cache3 libobrender29 libobt2
>   libpam-ck-connector   libxmmsclient-glib1 libxmmsclient6 lxappearance
>   lxde lxde-common lxde-core   lxde-icon-theme lxinput lxmenu-data
>   lxmusic lxpanel lxrandr lxsession   lxsession-data lxsession-edit
>   lxsession-logout lxshortcut lxterminal menu   menu-xdg obconf openbox
>   pcmanfm xarchiver xmms2-core xmms2-plugin-alsa   xmms2-plugin-id3v2
>   xmms2-plugin-mad xmms2-plugin-vorbis xscreensaver

Uninstall the ones you don't want with with:

> sudo apt-get remove package1 package2 package3.

Seems pretty "pure" to me enough. When I try with lubuntu-desktop I get WAY more packages.

But if all that is annoying you is the lubuntu-look compared to standard LXDE, just change it.. :)

Comment: Please include the command you used to generate the output you've posted. Also, please mention your starting point: by that, I mean which desktop environment is already installed. IMO, that would affect the output you've posted if the command I'm requesting is something like `apt-get install lxde`.